# Relation between the rank of a square matrix $M[c]$ and the polynomial $\det(M[x])$.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let
$$M[x]:=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}(x) &\dots& a_{1n}(x)\\
\vdots &\ddots& \vdots\\
a_{n1}(x) &\dots& a_{nn}(x)\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
be an $n\times n$ matrix with $a_{ij}(x)\in \mathbb{C}[x]$. Let $c\in \mathbb{C}$ and $0<rank(M[c])=r<n$. My question is, can we conclude anything about the multiplicity of $c$ as a root of $\det(M[x])$?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Pedro My guess is: the multiplicity of $c$ is at least $−$
, by looking at the cofactor formula of $\det([])$
.